# Не работает @client.event (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
C:\Users\name>py C:\Users\name\Desktop\logsbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arsenii\Desktop\logsbot.py", line 17, in <module>
    @client.event
     ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

Писал бота на питоне для логов дискорд

Comment: Вы переводчиком умеете пользоваться?) Ошибка говорит, что `client` не определён раньше.